# Parse tweet content out of embedded twitter timeline

Tags: javascript, php, twitter

I've been wondering and desperately digging into it without any success. Is there any way dig out the content/text of a tweet, put it in a variable or something - for later use?
It seems to be way over my head how to point it. 
It is buried under hundred different tags and the timeline is inside an iframe which loads after document is ready (I suppose).
Also, oddly enough, timeline seems to stop working at all (at least for me - it doesn't display at all) as soon as I start pointing anything inside of this iframe (I didn't touch the timeline code at all - for those who will suspect that I messed up the widget code).
Any help would be wonderfully helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using twitter API and some server side techology as ASP.Net or PHP ?

Comment: I was hoping I can just grab the content straight from DOM and play with it without going to deep into API. But now I'm so frustrated that this is probably the best idea. Won't get any sleep until this one is done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple if you use twitter api just put  $consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret(just sine up https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/sign-twitter and get keys ) copy my code make a class and call the function getTweets function

```
    function __construct()
     {
           include_once 'twitterApi/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php';
           /** set parameter for Twitter Api $consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret **/
           $this->connection = new TwitterOAuth('xxxxx','xxxx','xxxx-xxx','xxxx');
    }


   function getTweets($twitteruser,$nooftweets=30)
    {   /** fire query by api to get tweets **/
        $tweets = $this->objectToArray($this->connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets));

    /** get all tweets in single array */
    for($i= 0;$i<count($tweets); $i++)
    {
        $create[$i]                 = $tweets[$i]['created_at'];
        $tweet[$i]              = $tweets[$i]['text'];
        $retweetcount[$i]       = $tweets[$i]['retweet_count'];
        $favaritecount[$i]      = $tweets[$i]['favorite_count'];

        /** loop for get multipal #tags **/
        for($j=0;$j<=count($tweets[$i]['entities']['hashtags'])-1;$j++)
        {
            $hastag[$i]             .= $tweets[$i]['entities']['hashtags'][$j]['text'].',';
        }
    }
    return array('Tweet'=>$tweet,'Create'=>$create,'Retweetcount'=>$retweetcount,'Favaritecount'=>$favaritecount,'Hastag'=>$hastag);
}



public function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        // with get_object_vars function
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }

    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
         * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return array_map(array($this, 'objectToArray'), $d);
        //$this->d = get_object_vars($d);
    }
    else {
        // Return array
        return $d;
    }
}
```

Comment: After just a little tweak I got it working (needed to declare $hastag outside those loops and replace $hastag[$i] with $hastag[] because of the 'undefined offset'). But now I have a beautiful array of tweets :) thank you one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, `$('p.js-tweet-text.tweet-text')` should get you all the tweets on a page.

Comment: I've tried all that man... Maybe I was just doing this wrong but there is a jQuery conflict for starters. After that - everything seems to fall apart even further. Finally after hundrets of 'refresh' - even the timeline itself (in its purest form) stops working for couple of minutes. I'm just too dumm for this aproach - I guess :)